# Nginx fastcgi_cache_key with $http_cookie

Tags: php, drupal, session, caching, nginx

I'm trying to scale Drupal with nginx fastcgi caching.  I'm using

```
fastcgi_cache_key $http_cookie$request_method$host$request_uri;
fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_read_timeout 14400; 
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Drupal-Cache';
fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Generator';
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
fastcgi_cache drupal;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 1s;
fastcgi_cache_valid 302 1m;
fastcgi_cache_valid 404 1m;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500;     
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 2M;
add_header X-Micro-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
```

will there be any problems with users seeing pages they shouldn't?

I followed this guy's guide to micro caching

http://fennb.com/microcaching-speed-your-app-up-250x-with-no-n

but most of my website traffic is authenticated users, so I need to somehow cache those too.  I've tested on localhost but I'm not sure if I can use this on production.